# Creating XML with JAXB KieServicesClient fails (KIE 6.5.0)

Tags: xml, jaxb, kie, kie-server, drools-kie-server

I have an Object like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="com.Operation")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Operation implements java.io.Serializable
{

   static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @org.kie.api.definition.type.Label("systemCode")
   @XmlElement
   private int systemCode;
   [...]
```

When I marshall this manually with following code it seems it works well:

```
[...]
JAXBContext jaxbContext = 
DroolsJaxbHelperProviderImpl.createDroolsJaxbContext(classNames, null);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller(); 
StringWriter xml = new StringWriter(); 
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true); 
marshaller.marshal(object, System.out);
```

Hence the console prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <com.Operation>
    <systemCode>1</systemCode>
    [...]
```

But when I use the KieServerClient encouraged code I get an error:

```
org.kie.server.client.KieServicesException: Error while serializing request data!
at org.kie.server.client.impl.AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.serialize(AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.java:514)
at org.kie.server.client.impl.AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.makeHttpPostRequestAndCreateServiceResponse(AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.java:234)
at org.kie.server.client.impl.RuleServicesClientImpl.executeCommandsWithResults(RuleServicesClientImpl.java:72)
[...]
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
- with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class com.Operation ni ninguna de sus superclases se conocen en este contexto.
```

(The is in Spanish but I guess the error is pretty easy translated)

A snippet of the code I use for JAXB with KieServerClient:

```
KieCommands commandsFactory = KieServices.Factory.get().getCommands();

List<Command<?>> cmds = new ArrayList<Command<?>>();
BatchExecutionCommand command = commandsFactory.newBatchExecution(cmds, SESSION_STATEFUL);

Command<?> insertObjectCommand = null;
insertObjectCommand = commandsFactory.newInsert(operation, operation.getClass().getName(), false, null); 
cmds.add(insertObjectCommand);
[...]
KieServicesConfiguration config =  KieServicesFactory.newRestConfiguration(KieServer.urlKieServer,
                        KieServer.name,
                        KieServer.password);
config.setMarshallingFormat(MarshallingFormat.JAXB); 
KieServicesClient client = KieServicesFactory.newKieServicesClient(config);
RuleServicesClient rulesClient = client.getServicesClient(RuleServicesClient.class);  

ServiceResponse<ExecutionResults> response = rulesClient.executeCommandsWithResults("instances/"+containerName, command);
```

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong and why one marshalling works but the other does not?

Except for the POJO, I currently do not have this project under maven since I want to know what jars I actually need to have these projects working and with maven a lot of dependencies are automatically resolved and I basically have no clue what I need (my .m2 is full with downloaded jars I have no idea of).
Once resolved I will convert the project to maven.

Involved libraries are:

- droolsjbpm-integration-distribution-6.5.0.Final
- droolsjbpm-tools-distribution-6.5.0.Final
- httpclient-4.5.3
- httpcore-4.4.6
- javax.ws.rs-api-2.0
- jaxb-xjc-2.3.0
- jms-1.1
- kie-remote-client-6.5.0.Final
- kie-remote-common-6.5.0.Final
- kie-remote-jaxb-6.5.0.Final
- kie-server-api-6.5.0.Final
- kie-server-client-6.5.0.Final
- optaplanner-core-6.5.0.Final

Environment:
 - JBoss Developer Studio 10.4 
 - Wildfly 10.1 
 - JDK 1.8

PS: I have been able to connect to the KieServer via REST, but it is with the discouraged code and probably because of that (I guess, [nobody has ever answered me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45504210/serviceresponse-result-is-always-null-jaxb-kie-workbench-kie-server-6-5-0)) I don't obtain the response I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got the answer thanks to some guidelines I encountered on the RedHat webpage on Business Central: [FIRING RULES USING KIE SERVER JAVA CLIENT API](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_BRMS/6.2/html/Getting_Started_Guide/Firing_Rules_Using_Maven.html)

Key in this case was adding the classes to the configuration options for the Kie client. Code below is valid for connecting with KIE server via REST when using Drools/Kie workbench 6.5.0. *command* is a valid BatchExecutionCommand:

```
KieServicesConfiguration config =  KieServicesFactory.
                newRestConfiguration(KieServer.urlKieServer,
                        KieServer.name,
                        KieServer.password);
config.setMarshallingFormat(MarshallingFormat.JAXB); 
config.setTimeout(3000L); //optional
Set<Class<?>> allClasses = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
allClasses.add(YOURCLASS.class);
config.addExtraClasses(allClasses);

KieServicesClient client = KieServicesFactory.newKieServicesClient(config);
RuleServicesClient rulesClient = client.getServicesClient(RuleServicesClient.class);  

ServiceResponse<ExecutionResults> response = rulesClient.executeCommandsWithResults(containerName, command);
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I have an example project on github [link](https://github.com/eggsandbutter/kieservices).

Comment: Using the KieServicesClient  with config for connection is the way to go. In the version 7 is all the same, just some code from remote library is moved to kie-server-client api, as Workbench is left without internal server from version 7.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the confirmation! I need to make the switch soon to version 7. Drools has evolved very rapidly this last year.